# C Custom Headers for intellisense in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

In our C/C++ project for the C part we use 2 types of headers, .h and .p (internally referred as prototypes).
I'm making the shift from Eclipse to VSCode. All is good but one thing, VSCode's intellisense only sees .h files but it's completely unaware of the .p .
I have to add each folder containing .p files by hand and this is pretty annoying give the overwhelmingly huge size of the project.

I searched around the network but I can't seem to find an answer to such a simple question: how do I tell VSCode's ms-vscode.cpptools that headers are also of .p extension?

Comment: Suggest correcting the 'C' language header file names to ALL end in `.h`  Note, however, that `C++` header files, typically, have no extension

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible. Changing that would create a big amount of work because of the size of the project and .p were decided to exist to give you extra info at a glance. It's not up to me changing that. :(

Comment: a simple script, For instance, written in BASH, can easily change all `#include <something.p>`  to `#include <something.h>`   A very similar script can change the file  name extensions from `.p` to `,h`  In general this is the kind of activity used to re-format any file within a project,  The only work would be writing the two scripts

Comment: When I said "a big amount of work", I mainly referred to lengthy bureaucracy of having meeting with all engineers, architects and some managers and get this all things in motion. I'd have preferred a simple setting in VSCode to tell it what to classify "as header".